# Windows 7 Lost Aero Theme

Tags: windows

My windows 7 home premium lost the aero theme last week some time. I can't remember if I had installed or changed anything but I don't think I did. The computer knows full well that its running windows classic theme, and the aero themes are not grayed out. When I click the Windows 7 default theme, the background changes but the window styles do not. It won't even switch to nontransparent rounded windows. System restore fails because it says a file couldn't be replaced so nothing was changed. DWM.exe is running, the theme service is running, and Microsoft Support couldn't do anything without me paying. I'm a computer programmer but when it comes to windows I'm just not sure. I've tried everything I know. Any help would be appreciated. Don't be afraid to throw technical terms at me.

Thanks!

**Edit:** here are the results of dxdiag:

[image: Everything looks fine to me.]

Comment: Are your graphic drivers current?

Comment: I believe they are. The computer's GPU has the current driver and the monitor says... Oh it says Generic PnP monitor. I don't recall what it said before. It's a HP laptop so the monitor is probably very precise about the driver. I dual boot with Ubuntu and it works fine in terms of graphics performance.

Comment: You believe?  Its easy enough to confirm.  post the information from `dxdiag`.  I need specific exact details in order to guide you "you think" or "you believe" statements are not helpful in a troubleshooting.

Comment: Sorry about the vague statements. I just don't want to tell you something that I'm not sure about and mislead you. I added the results of `dxdiag`

Comment: Your drivers are 2 years old.  I would find the latest version of the driver that your card supports and use that.  [**14.4 supports your card.**](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download)

Comment: Try updating your drivers using Windows Update, it's the easiest way. Or you can manually search and install them if you want.

Comment: Before I do that, is it possible that a failing LCD connector could be causing this problem? Maybe windows can't decide what kind of screen it is so it it calls it a Generic PnP and won't push aero on it? Its also important to note that the aero options are not grayed out so the driver is supported. Because the System Restore is corrupt, is it possible that whatever makes DWM work is also corrupt?